# Prove that every simple polygon has a ear without resorting to triangulation

Tags: proof-writing, computational-geometry, triangulation

We can establish the existence of a triangulation for each [simple polygon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_polygon) relying on the fact that every simple polygon has at least one [ear](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ear_(mathematics)), utilizing induction.

Conversely, we can establish that every simple polygon has 2 ears based on triangulation, since every simple polygon with $n$ edges can be triangulated into $n-2$ triangles, where each triangle shares at most 2 edges with the polygon.

My question is: Can we prove that every polygon has a ear without resorting to triangulation?

Comment: Can we use that every polygon (except triangles) has a diagonal? If so, it’s an easy induction.

Comment: @lhf Yes. I didn't realize it then, but now I've come to understand.

Comment: Also [Meisters 1975](https://www.cgeo.uliege.be/CG/polygons_have_ears.pdf) has the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. We'll prove a stronger claim by induction:

> For every simple polygon $P$, and every side $AB$ of that polygon, $P$ has an ear whose central vertex is neither $A$ nor $B$.

(By finding one ear, then applying this claim with one side of the first ear as our $AB$, this gives us the second ear, so in fact this claim directly shows that every polygon has two ears without proving triangulation as a lemma.)

The claim is obvious for triangles.

Now suppose we've shown it up to $(n-1)$-gons, and take $P$ to have vertices $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4, \ldots, P_n$ in cyclic order. We'll take $A,B=P_1,P_2$ without loss of generality, so we want to find an ear somewhere on $P_3,\ldots,P_n$.

Since every polygon has at least three convex angles, there's at least one other vertex $P_k$ with a convex angle. If $C$ is the vertex of an ear, we're done; otherwise, there is at least one point within the interior of the triangle $\Delta P_{k-1}P_kP_{k+1}$. Choose one such point $P_j$ such that the line from $P_k$ to $P_j$ is fully within the polygon.*

Now, cut our polygon in two along the line segment $P_kP_j$ (by assumption, $j$ wasn't $k-1$ or $k+1$, so these two pieces really are nontrivial polygons). AB will be on one of these two pieces; consider the other piece. By the inductive hypothesis, that piece has an ear disjoint from $P_kP_j$. But that ear is also an ear of the original polygon and is not on AB, so we're done!

*It's not immediately obvious that this is possible, because it might be the case that any point we try to reach in the triangle is separated from us by a squiggle in the boundary of our polygon. But it turns out we can always do this: just choose the point $P_j$ in the interior of the triangle which is closest to $P_k$ along the axis orthogonal to $\overline{P_{k-1}P_{k+1}}$. If an edge of the polygon were to cross over the line segment $P_kP_j$ and interrupt our path, then one side of that edge would have to be even closer to $P_k$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Nice claim and nice proof by induction! I come to understand that each vertex is either the center of an ear, or contained in a diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

If the polygon is a triangle, then it is an ear.

Otherwise, [the polygon has a diagonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1103318/589). That diagonal divides the polygon into two disjoint polygons. By induction on the number of vertices, these two parts have ears.

Comment: Just because the two parts have ears doesn't necessarily mean the original does - one must show that the ears of the parts are disjoint from the diagonal used to make the cut.

Comment: We can iteratively divide the polygon by diagonals. At each step, we choose the portion that shares all its edges with the polygon, except for the cut edge. This process ultimately yields an ear.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. If angle ABC where A,B,C are consecutive vertices of polygon is convex ( smaller than 180 deg) then B is ear directly from definition of convex set

Comment: A non-convex polygon does not necessarily have three consecutive convex vertices.

Comment: The conclusion does not follow. If you have a quadrilateral with $A=(0,3)$, $B=(0,0)$, $C=(3,0)$, $D=(1,1)$, then $A$, $B$, $C$ have angles less than $180$ but $B$ is not an ear. The angles at $A$,$C$ say nothing about whether or not some other vertex lies inside triangle $ABC$.